# TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

This is my models.py file

```
    class Tag(models.Model):

        name = models.CharField(max_length=31, unique=True)
        slug = models.SlugField(max_length=31, unique=True, help_text = 'A label for URL config')
    
        class Meta:
          ordering = ['name']
    
        def __str__(self):
             return self.name.title()
    
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('organizer_tag_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
        
        def get_update_url(self):
            return reverse('organizer_tag_update', kwargs={'slug' : self.slug})
        def get_delete_url(self):
            return reverse('organizer_tag_delete', kwargs={'slug':self.slug}) 
    
    class StartUp(models.Model):

         name = models.CharField(max_length=31, db_index=True)
         slug = models.SlugField(max_length=31,unique=True, help_text='A label for URL config')
         description = models.TextField()
         founded_date = models.DateField()
         contact = models.EmailField('date founded')
         website = models.URLField()
         tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    
        class Meta:
           ordering = ['name']
           get_latest_by = 'founded_date'
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
        def get_absolute_url(self):
          return reverse('organizer_startup_detail', kwargs={'slug':self.slug })
    
        def get_update_url(self):
          return reverse('organizer_startup_update', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
    
        def get_delete_url(self):
         return reverse('organizer_startup_delete', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    class NewsLink(models.Model):

         title = models.CharField(max_length=63)
         slug = models.SlugField(max_length=63)
         pub_date = models.DateField('date published')
         link = models.URLField(max_length=255)
         startup = models.ForeignKey(StartUp, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
       class Meta:
             verbose_name ='news article'
             ordering = ['-pub_date']
             get_latest_by = 'pub_date'
             unique_together = ('slug', 'startup')
    
    
        def __str__(self):
            return "{} : {}" .format(
            self.startup, self.title
        )

        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return self.startup.get_absolute_url()
    
        def get_update_url(self):
            return reverse('organizer_newslink_update', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
    
        def get_delete_url(self):
            return reverse('organizer_newslink_delete', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

Here is my 0005_newslink_data migration file

```
from django.db import migrations, models
from datetime import date

NEWSLINKS = [
    {
        "title" :"Redundant Homepage Link",
        "link": "http://jambonsw.com",
        "pub_date" : date(2013,1, 18),
        "startup" : "jambon-software",
        
},
    {
        "title": "Monkey(Wikipedia)",
        "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey",
         "pub_date" : date(2012, 7, 22),
         "startup" : "monkey-software",
    },
    {
        "title" : "William Shakespeare",
        "link" : "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Shakespeare",
        "pub_date" : date(2014, 4, 26),
        "startup" : "monkey-software",
    },
]

    def add_newslink_data(apps, schema_editor):

       NewsLink = apps.get_model('organizer', 'NewsLink')
       StartUp  = apps.get_model('organizer', 'StartUp')
       for newslink_dict in NEWSLINKS:
             newslink = NewsLink.objects.create(
                 title = newslink_dict['title'],
                 link = newslink_dict['link'],
                 pub_date = newslink_dict['pub_date'],
                 startup = StartUp.objects.get( 
                 slug = newslink_dict['startup']))

     def remove_newslink_data(apps, schema_editor):

         NewsLink = apps.get_model('organizer', 'NewsLink')
         StartUp = apps.get_model('organizer', 'StartUp')
        
         for newslink_dict in NEWSLINK:
             newslink = NewsLink.objects.get(
                 title = newslink_dict['title'],
                 link = newslink_dict['link'],
                 pub_date = newslink_dict['pub_date'],
                 startup  = StartUp.objects.get(
                 slug = newslink_dict['startup']))
                  newslink.delete()
            
            
    class Migration(migrations.Migration):
        dependencies = [
              ('organizer', '0004_startup_data'),
    ]

         operations = [
               migrations.RunPython(add_newslink_data, remove_newslink_data)
    ]
```

here is my startup_data migration file

````
from django.db import migrations
from datetime import date


STARTUPS = [
  {
    "name" : "Arachnobots",
    "slug": "arachnobots",
    "contact": "contact@arachnobots.com",
    "description":
        "Remote-controlled-internet-enabled"
        "Spider Robots",
    "founded_date": date(2014, 10, 31),
    "tags" : ["mobile", "augmented-reality"],
    "website" :
            "http://frightenyourroommate.com/"

  },
  {
      "name" : "Boundless-Software",
      "slug" : "boundless-software",
      "contact" : "hello@boundless.com",
      "description" : "The Sky was the limit",
      "founded_date" :  date(2013, 5, 15),
      "tags" : ["big-data"],
      "website" : "http://boundless.com"
  },
  {
      "name" : "Game Congress",
      "slug" : "game-congress",
      "contact" : "vote@gamecongress.com",
      "description" : "By gamers for gamers of gamers",
      "founded_date" : date(2012, 7, 4),
      "tags" : ["video-games"],
      "website" : "http://gamecongress.com/",
  },
  {
      "name" : "JamBon Software",
      "slug" : "jambon-software",
      "contact" : "django@jambonsw.com",
      "description": "JamBon Software is a consulting "
            "company that specializes in web and "
            "mobile products. They can carry out "
            "Full end to end development of new "
            "products, or review and advise on existing "
            "products. They also offer hands on training in "
            "Django.",
        "founded_date" : date(2013, 1, 18),
        "tags" : ["django"],
        "website" : "http://jambonsw.com"
            
  },
  {
      "name" : "Lightning Rod Challenge",
      "slug" : "lightning-rod-challenge",
      "contact" : "hello@lightningrode.com",
      "description" :
          "Channel the storm "
          "Trouble shoot the cloud.",
       "founded_date" : date(2014,1,1),
       "tags" : ["ipython", "jupyter", "big-data"],
       "website" : "http://lightningrode.com",
  },
  {
      "name" : "Monkey Software",
      "slug" : "monkey-software",
      "contact" : "shakespear@monkeysw.com",
      "description" :
          "1000 code monkey making software.",
      "founded_date" : date(2014, 12, 10),
      "tags" : ["video-games"],
      "website" : "http://monkeysw.com/",
  },
  {
      "name": "Simple Robots",
      "slug" : "simple-robots",
      "contact" : "yoshimi@simplerobots.com",
      "description" :
            "Your resource to understanding "
            "computer, robots, and technology.",
      "founded_date" : date(2010, 1, 2),
      "tags" : ["python", "augmented-reality"],
      "website" : "http://simplerobots.com/",
  },
  {
      "name" : "Thingles",
      "slug" : "thingles",
      "contact" : "help@lightningrod.com",
      "description" :
          "A market place for arduino, "
          "raspberry pi, and other "
          "homemade stuff.",
     "founded_date" : date(2015, 4, 7),
     "tags" : ["python"],
     "website" :"http://buythingles.com/",
  },
]

    
    def add_startup_data(apps, scheme_editor):

        StartUp = apps.get_model('organizer', 'StartUp')
        Tag = apps.get_model('organizer', 'Tag')
       
         for startup in STARTUPS:
             startup_object = StartUp.objects.create(
                    name = startup['name'],
                    slug = startup['slug'],
                    contact = startup['contact'],
                    description = startup['description'],
                    founded_date = startup['founded_date'],
                    website = startup['website'])
             for tag_slug in startup['tags']:
                       startup_object.tags.add(
                Tag.objects.get(slug=tag_slug)
                )
                
    
     def remove_startup_data(app, scheme_editor):

         StartUp = apps.get_model('organizer', 'StartUp')
         for startup in STARTUPS:
                startup_object = StartUp.objects.get(slug=startup['slug'])
                startup_object.delete()
        
    class Migration(migrations.Migration):
         dependencies = [
               ('organizer', '0003_tag_data'),
            ]

         operations = [
                migrations.RunPython(add_startup_data, remove_startup_data)
          ]
```
````

While Running migrations :
Applying organizer.0005_newslink_data...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute

    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute

    return super().execute(query, params)

sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: organizer_newslink.slug, organizer_newslink.startup_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 252, in apply_migration

    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py", line 132, in apply

    operation.database_forwards(

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\special.py", line 193, in database_forwards    ` 

    self.code(from_state.apps, schema_editor)`

File "E:\Django Unleashed\suorganizer\organizer\migrations\0005_newslink_data.py", line 33, in `add_newslink_data`

    newslink = NewsLink.objects.create(

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 87, in manager_method

    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)       

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 658, in create

    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 814, in save

    self.save_base(

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 877, in save_base

    updated = self._save_table(

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1020, in _save_table

    results = self._do_insert(

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1061, in _do_insert

    return manager._insert(

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 87, in manager_method

    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)       

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1805, in _insert

    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(returning_fields)

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1820, in execute_sql

    cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 102, in execute

    return super().execute(sql, params)

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute

    return self._execute_with_wrappers(

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers

    return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute

    with self.db.wrap_database_errors:

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 91, in __exit__
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value      
File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 89, in _execute

    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 328, in execute

    return super().execute(query, params)

django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: organizer_newslink.slug, organizer_newslink.startup_id

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception: 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:\Django Unleashed\suorganizer\manage.py", line 22, in <module>

    main()

File "E:\Django Unleashed\suorganizer\manage.py", line 18, in main 

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 442, in execute_from_command_line    utility.execute()
File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 436, in execute

    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 412, in run_from_argv

    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in execute

    output = self.handle(*args, **options)

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 106, in wrapper

    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 356, in handle

    post_migrate_state = executor.migrate(

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 135, in migrate

    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 167, in _migrate_all_forwards      

    state = self.apply_migration(

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 249, in apply_migration

    with self.connection.schema_editor(

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py", line 38, in __exit__

    self.connection.check_constraints()

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py", line 244, in check_constraints        

    violations = cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_key_check").fetchall()

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 102, in execute

    return super().execute(sql, params)

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute

    return self._execute_with_wrappers(

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 80, in _execute_with_wrappers

    return executor(sql, params, many, context)

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 83, in _execute

    self.db.validate_no_broken_transaction()

File "E:\Django Unleashed\django-unleashed\lib\site-packages\django    raise TransactionManagementError(
django.db.transaction.TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.
```

i did python manage.py migrate after writing migartions files for my apps in django project and while Running migrations:   Applying organizer.0005_newslink_data...Traceback (most recent call last):
TransactionManagementError: An error occurred in the current transaction. You can't execute queries until the end of the 'atomic' block.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that these two are causing `IntegrityError`:

```
{
        "title": "Monkey(Wikipedia)",
        "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey",
         "pub_date" : date(2012, 7, 22),
         "startup" : "monkey-software",
    },
    {
        "title" : "William Shakespeare",
        "link" : "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Shakespeare",
        "pub_date" : date(2014, 4, 26),
        "startup" : "monkey-software",
    },
```

Its the same `startup` & `slug` (which is not been assigned although it cant be blank or null, by your definition).

try to change the `startup` attribute for one of them.

also, it will be helpful to read the default values for `null` & `blank` fields options from the django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#null

Comment: do you mean to change the startup which is monkey-software in one of these

Comment: can you please simply explain what should i change in my code

Comment: you have a constraint in the `newslink` model, that you ignore from.
look at the model. (`unique_together = ('slug', 'startup')`)