# raise Http404( django.http.response.Http404: No StartUp matches the given query

Tags: python, django

newslink migration file

```
from django.db import migrations, models
from datetime import date
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
    
    NEWSLINKS = [
        {
            "title" :"Redundant Homepage Link",
            "link": "http://jambonsw.com",
            "pub_date" : date(2013,1, 18),
            "startup" : "jambon-software",
            
    },
        {
            "title": "Monkey(Wikipedia)",
            "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey",
             "pub_date" : date(2012, 7, 22),
             "startup" : "monkey-software",
        },
        {
            "title" : "William Shakespeare",
            "link" : "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Shakespeare",
            "pub_date" : date(2014, 4, 26),
            "startup" : "monkey-hardware",
        },
    ]
    
    def add_newslink_data(apps, schema_editor):
        NewsLink = apps.get_model('organizer', 'NewsLink')
        StartUp  = apps.get_model('organizer', 'StartUp')
        for newslink_dict in NEWSLINKS:
            newslink = NewsLink.objects.create(
                title = newslink_dict['title'],
                link = newslink_dict['link'],
                pub_date = newslink_dict['pub_date'],
                startup = get_object_or_404(StartUp, 
                slug = newslink_dict['startup']))
    
    def remove_newslink_data(apps, schema_editor):
        NewsLink = apps.get_model('organizer', 'NewsLink')
        StartUp = apps.get_model('organizer', 'StartUp')
            
        for newslink_dict in NEWSLINKS:
            newslink = NewsLink.objects.get(
            title = newslink_dict['title'],
            link = newslink_dict['link'],
            pub_date = newslink_dict['pub_date'],
            startup  = StartUp.objects.get(
            slug = newslink_dict['startup']))
            newslink.delete()
                
                
    class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    
        dependencies = [
            ('organizer', '0004_startup_data'),
        ]
    
        operations = [
            migrations.RunPython(add_newslink_data, remove_newslink_data)
```

startup migration file

```
from django.db import migrations
from datetime import date
    
    
    STARTUPS = [
      {
        "name" : "Arachnobots",
        "slug": "arachnobots",
        "contact": "contact@arachnobots.com",
        "description":
            "Remote-controlled-internet-enabled"
            "Spider Robots",
        "founded_date": date(2014, 10, 31),
        "tags" : ["mobile", "augmented-reality"],
        "website" :
                "http://frightenyourroommate.com/"
    
      },
      {
          "name" : "Boundless-Software",
          "slug" : "boundless-software",
          "contact" : "hello@boundless.com",
          "description" : "The Sky was the limit",
          "founded_date" :  date(2013, 5, 15),
          "tags" : ["big-data"],
          "website" : "http://boundless.com"
      },
      {
          "name" : "Game Congress",
          "slug" : "monkey-hardware",
          "contact" : "vote@gamecongress.com",
          "description" : "By gamers for gamers of gamers",
          "founded_date" : date(2012, 7, 4),
          "tags" : ["video-games"],
          "website" : "http://gamecongress.com/",
      },
      {
          "name" : "JamBon Software",
          "slug" : "jambon-software",
          "contact" : "django@jambonsw.com",
          "description": "JamBon Software is a consulting "
                "company that specializes in web and "
                "mobile products. They can carry out "
                "Full end to end development of new "
                "products, or review and advise on existing "
                "products. They also offer hands on training in "
                "Django.",
            "founded_date" : date(2013, 1, 18),
            "tags" : ["django"],
            "website" : "http://jambonsw.com"
                
      },
      {
          "name" : "Lightning Rod Challenge",
          "slug" : "lightning-rod-challenge",
          "contact" : "hello@lightningrode.com",
          "description" :
              "Channel the storm "
              "Trouble shoot the cloud.",
           "founded_date" : date(2014,1,1),
           "tags" : ["ipython", "jupyter", "big-data"],
           "website" : "http://lightningrode.com",
      },
      {
          "name" : "Monkey Software",
          "slug" : "monkey-software",
          "contact" : "shakespear@monkeysw.com",
          "description" :
              "1000 code monkey making software.",
          "founded_date" : date(2014, 12, 10),
          "tags" : ["video-games"],
          "website" : "http://monkeysw.com/",
      },
      {
          "name": "Simple Robots",
          "slug" : "simple-robots",
          "contact" : "yoshimi@simplerobots.com",
          "description" :
                "Your resource to understanding "
                "computer, robots, and technology.",
          "founded_date" : date(2010, 1, 2),
          "tags" : ["python", "augmented-reality"],
          "website" : "http://simplerobots.com/",
      },
      {
          "name" : "Thingles",
          "slug" : "thingles",
          "contact" : "help@lightningrod.com",
          "description" :
              "A market place for arduino, "
              "raspberry pi, and other "
              "homemade stuff.",
         "founded_date" : date(2015, 4, 7),
         "tags" : ["python"],
         "website" :"http://buythingles.com/",
      },
    ]
    
        
    def add_startup_data(apps, scheme_editor):
    
           StartUp = apps.get_model('organizer', 'StartUp')
           Tag = apps.get_model('organizer', 'Tag')
           
           for startup in STARTUPS:
               startup_object = StartUp.objects.create(
                   name = startup['name'],
                   slug = startup['slug'],
                   contact = startup['contact'],
                   description = startup['description'],
                   founded_date = startup['founded_date'],
                   website = startup['website'])
               for tag_slug in startup['tags']:
                    startup_object.tags.add(
                    Tag.objects.get(slug=tag_slug)
                    )
                    
        
    def remove_startup_data(app, scheme_editor):
        StartUp = apps.get_model('organizer', 'StartUp')
        for startup in STARTUPS:
            startup_object = StartUp.objects.get(slug=startup['slug'])
            startup_object.delete()
            
    class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    
        dependencies = [
            ('organizer', '0003_tag_data'),
        ]
    
        operations = [
            migrations.RunPython(add_startup_data, remove_startup_data)
```

models file

```
   
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse   
   
   class Tag(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=31, unique=True)
       slug = models.SlugField(max_length=31, unique=True, help_text = 'A label for URL config')
       
       class Meta:
           ordering = ['name']
       
       def __str__(self):
           return self.name.title()
       
       def get_absolute_url(self):
           return reverse('organizer_tag_detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
           
       def get_update_url(self):
           return reverse('organizer_tag_update', kwargs={'slug' : self.slug})
       def get_delete_url(self):
           return reverse('organizer_tag_delete', kwargs={'slug':self.slug}) 
       
   class StartUp(models.Model):
       name = models.CharField(max_length=31, db_index=True)
       slug = models.SlugField(max_length=31,unique=True, help_text='A label for URL config')
       description = models.TextField()
       founded_date = models.DateField()
       contact = models.EmailField('date founded')
       website = models.URLField()
       tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
       
       class Meta:
           ordering = ['name']
           get_latest_by = 'founded_date'
       
       def __str__(self):
           return self.name
       
       def get_absolute_url(self):
           return reverse('organizer_startup_detail', kwargs={'slug':self.slug })
       
       def get_update_url(self):
           return reverse('organizer_startup_update', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
       
       def get_delete_url(self):
           return reverse('organizer_startup_delete', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
   
   class NewsLink(models.Model):
       title = models.CharField(max_length=63)
       slug = models.SlugField(max_length=63)
       pub_date = models.DateField('date published')
       link = models.URLField(max_length=255)
       startup = models.ForeignKey(StartUp, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
       
       class Meta:
           verbose_name ='news article'
           ordering = ['-pub_date']
           get_latest_by = 'pub_date'
           unique_together = ('slug', 'startup')
       
       
       def __str__(self):
           return "{} : {}" .format(
               self.startup, self.title
           )
   
       def get_absolute_url(self):
           return self.startup.get_absolute_url()
       
       def get_update_url(self):
           return reverse('organizer_newslink_update', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
       
       def get_delete_url(self):
           return reverse('organizer_newslink_delete', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})
```

whenever i am running command python manage.py migrate error is coming. sometimes raise self.model Does not exist. now Http 404 after adding get_object_or_404 and before adding this there was error transaction management error.

Comment: please fix code indentation and put your question upfront. It would also help rewriting the question for clarity

Comment: what do you mean by upfront and  ok i will fix my code indentation but can you tell whats the error

Comment: upfront: before the code (now it is at the very end, after a wall of code). Revising for clarity: after reading the question, I still have no idea what's the problem. Indentation: there are a bunch of imports preceding each file's content - they are not indented properly

Comment: ok see this question it is same code but i think it is indented https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76195650/transactionmanagementerror-an-error-occurred-in-the-current-transaction-you-ca